# Trying to regex match null in Spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, null, nonetype

I have issue with null on Spark DF which I want to overcome. Let's say I have this spark DF:

```py
spark_df.show()

# Output
# +----+----+
# |keys|vals|
# +----+----+
# |  k1|   0|
# |  k2|   1|
# |  k3|null|
# +----+----+
```

And I have these functions:

```py
def add_col_by_vals():
   df_with_col = spark_df.withColumn('target_col', get_column())
   return df_with_col 

def get_column():
    return ~f.lower(f.col("vals")).rlike("0|null|None")
```

The expected result is:

```
df_after_add_col = add_col_by_vals()
df_after_add_col.show()

# Output
# +----+----+----------+
# |keys|vals|target_col|
# +----+----+----------+
# |  k1|   0|     false|
# |  k2|   1|      true|
# |  k3|null|     false|
# +----+----+----------+
```

The actual result is:

```
df_after_add_col = add_col_by_vals()
df_after_add_col.show()

# Output
# +----+----+----------+
# |keys|vals|target_col|
# +----+----+----------+
# |  k1|   0|     false|
# |  k2|   1|      true|
# |  k3|null|      null|
# +----+----+----------+
```

I understand there is a problem with null. I don't want to change the DF at all, the only place I can change something in the code is `get_column` function.

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: `null` and `"null"` are not same. maybe you want to do `func.col('column').isNull()` for the null check

Comment: yes but can I combine .isNull() and .rlike?

Comment: yes, you can create a condition with & (and) | (or)

Answer (score 0):

Regex works with strings (null is not a string). If you provide null, you will get null. You will have to use another function to deal with nulls. You could use `coalesce`. It will return `False` if the result of regex is null.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

spark_df = spark.createDataFrame([("k1", 0), ("k2", 1), ("k3", None)], ["keys", "vals"])

def add_col_by_vals():
   df_with_col = spark_df.withColumn('target_col', get_column())
   return df_with_col 

def get_column():
    return F.coalesce(~F.lower("vals").rlike("0"), F.lit(False))

add_col_by_vals().show()
# +----+----+----------+
# |keys|vals|target_col|
# +----+----+----------+
# |  k1|   0|     false|
# |  k2|   1|      true|
# |  k3|null|     false|
# +----+----+----------+
```